# Width for divs in email

Tags: css, email, outlook

I am to style an html email. As it looks like the CSS width/height property will not work for divs in Outlook. Is there a way around this besides using the old fashioned way of using tables?

Comment: Share the efforts you made so far. Check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to use tables. Here is a great tool to convert divs to tables. http://divtable.com/

Another wonderful tool you can use is : http://pulp.glitchpack.com/builder